# The SharePoint API for retrieiving all user groups and users who have access to a file

Tags: sharepoint-api

We are looking for a SharePoint API that provides all the users/groups which have access to a file in SharePoint if we know the URL of that document.

I looked in SPItem Class of MSDN documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms443717.aspx and could not find any method that provides this information.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this for SharePoint 2007 or 2010

For 2007 you can use

```
ISecurableObject.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
```

Any object in SharePoint that is securable will use this interface. You can then see if the object has unique security or inherits from a parent object.

You could then keep going back along the parents untill you find the unique secure object (SPSite for example)

To see what permissions are applied to a SPSecurableObject look at the RoleAssignments property and the SPRoleAssignment